# Preloading set of images using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of images that are frames in an animation like: `frame-1.jpg, frame-2.jpg` and I have about 400 images.

What I want to do is preload these 400 images before the animation starts.

Usually when preloading images I use the following:

```
var images = [
        'img/nav-one-selected.png',
        'img/nav-two-selected.png',
        'img/nav-three-selected.png',
        'img/nav-four-selected.png'
    ];

    $(images).each(function() {
        var image = $('<img />').attr('src', this);
    });
```

But in this instance, listing the images in the var isn't feasible, and I also wish to fire off the start animation once the images have all been loaded.

So far I have the following:

```
$spinner_currentFrame = 1;
$numFrames = 400;

function preloadImages() {
    $($images).each(function() {
        var image = $('<img />').attr('src', this);
    });
    startAnimation();
}

function startAnimation() {
    $spinner_loadingAnim = setInterval(function () {
        UpdateSpinner();
    }, 140);
}

function UpdateSpinner() {
    $spinner_currentFrame = $spinner_currentFrame + 1;
    if($spinner_currentFrame > $numFrames) {
        $spinner_currentFrame = 1;
    }
    console.log($spinner_currentFrame);
    $('#spinner').css("background-image", "url(frame-" + $spinner_currentFrame + ".jpg)");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    preloadImages();
});
```

So the plan is that I preload images that are from 1 to 400 and then once that's completed then start the animation. How would I build the $images var though?

I've thought about something like:

```
$images = [];
$frame = 1;
$numFrames = 400;
$($frame).each(function() {

    $frame = $frame + 1;
    if($frame <= $numFrames) {

     $images =+ 'frame-' + $frame + '.jpg';

    }

});
```

But I'm not sure how a) efficient this is and b) how to do the callback once all images have loaded successfully.

Comment: When transfering so many files (400+) you should start considering using a technique like https://github.com/jAndreas/Supply

Comment: Still need to populate the list which is what the question is asking :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a standard javascript for loop instead of the jQuery's foreach. Foreach is wonderful for looping over an array or set of objects, but not in this case. Here is an example, please note that you have to bind the onload event handler before you set the Image object's src property.

UPDATE: added more functions to complete the entire example.

```
var loaded_images = 0;
var frames = 400;
var images = [];

function preloadImages() {
    for (i=0; i < frames; i++) {
        images[i] = new Image();
        images[i].onload = function() {
            loaded_images += 1;
            checkLoadingFinished();
        }
        images[i].src = 'frame-' + i + '.jpg';
    }
}

function checkLoadingFinished() {
    if (loaded_images >= frames) {
        startAnimation();
    }
}

function startAnimation() {
    var frameNumber = 0;
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        $('#img-dom-element').attr('src', images[frameNumber]);

        if (frameNumber > frames) {
            frameNumber = 0;
        else
            frameNumber++;

    }, (1000/30)); // (1000/30) = 30 frames per second
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    preloadImages();
});
```

Comment: please note that this is not tested nor production ready code, I just wrote it off the top of my head. Instead it is meant to give you an idea on how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if it fits to your special case but I use 
http://thinkpixellab.com/pxloader/
to preload images. You can add the paths and get one callback if all images are loaded. Afterwards you can start animation.